# Type hints for mypy for a decorator over staticmethod/classmethod

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy

I'm writing a helper for logger library that has decorators with specific logging for trace (debugging).

The code itself is correct (it is partially based on existing library), but i struggle to find how to make mypy accept types for it.

Question marks is where i have problems with types. Or maybe the problem is more general

For staticmethod:

```
def trace_static_method(_staticmethod: staticmethod) -> staticmethod:
    @wraps(_staticmethod.__func__)  # this generate mypy error for incorrect type
    def wrapper(*args: ???, **kwargs: ???) -> ???:
        return _log_trace(_staticmethod.__func__, *args, **kwargs)
    return staticmethod(wrapper)  # this generate mypy error for incorrect type
```

For classmethod:

```
def trace_class_method(_classmethod: classmethod) -> classmethod:
    @wraps(_classmethod.__func__)  # this generate mypy error for incorrect type
    def wrapper(_cls: ???, *args: ???, **kwargs: ???) -> ???:
        method = _classmethod.__get__(None, _cls)  # this generate mypy error for incorrect type
        return _log_trace(method, *args, **kwargs)
    return classmethod(wrapper)  # this generate mypy error for incorrect type
```

Log trace:

```
def _log_trace(func: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
    name = func.__qualname__
    module = func.__module__
    logger_ = logger.opt(depth=1)
    logger_.log("TRACE", "{}.{} CALL args={}, kwargs={}", module, name, args, kwargs)
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    logger_.log("TRACE", "{}.{} RETURN {}", module, name, result)
    return result
```

Working types for a simple function decorator:

```
def trace(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        return _log_trace(func, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

**EDIT**: adding correct types for static method was actually pretty straightforward:

```
def trace_static_method(_staticmethod: staticmethod[P, T]) -> staticmethod[P, T]:

    @wraps(_staticmethod.__func__)
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        return _log_trace(_staticmethod.__func__, *args, **kwargs)

    return staticmethod(wrapper)
```

Comment: Why can't you just decorate the class/static methods with `@trace`?

Comment: @Samwise i didn't include full library code. The staticmethod/classmethod must be top level decorator and i can't control it if i wrap whole class to automatically decorate all methods

Comment: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3482 well.

Comment: Turns out, mypy up to 1.5.1 doesn't have the correct overload for `__get__` method of classmethod as well. It is correct in current master branch, so next release will fix at least this, i will return to this when it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct typings. Works with mypy 1.6.1.

```py
P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")
R_co = TypeVar("R_co", covariant=True)

def _log_trace(func: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
    """Log a function call and return."""
    trace_logger = logger.opt(depth=1).bind(
        trace_name=func.__qualname__,
        trace_module=func.__module__,
    )
    trace_logger.trace("CALL args={}, kwargs={}", args, kwargs)
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    trace_logger.trace("RETURN {}", result)
    return result

def trace(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
    """Trace a function."""

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        return _log_trace(func, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


def trace_instance_method(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
    """Trace a method."""

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        _self: object = args[0]
        method = func.__get__(_self, _self.__class__)
        return _log_trace(method, *args[1:], **kwargs)

    return wrapper


def trace_static_method(
    _staticmethod: "staticmethod[P, R_co]",
) -> "staticmethod[P, R_co]":
    """Trace a method wrapped in @staticmethod."""

    @wraps(_staticmethod.__func__)
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R_co:
        return _log_trace(_staticmethod.__func__, *args, **kwargs)

    return staticmethod(wrapper)


def trace_class_method(
    _classmethod: "classmethod[T, P, R_co]",
) -> "classmethod[T, P, R_co]":
    """Trace a method wrapped in @classmethod"""

    @wraps(_classmethod.__func__)
    def wrapper(_cls: type[T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R_co:
        method = _classmethod.__get__(None, _cls)
        return _log_trace(method, *args, **kwargs)

    return classmethod(wrapper)
```